# Angular: Diffenrence between $router and $rootRouter?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, provider, angular-component-router

I was implementing webpack to my angularJS project the other day, and my project threw an unkown RouterProvider error.

Changing my `$router` provider to `$rootRouter` fixed the issue.
So my question is, what is the difference between them?

Thanks in advance,
Jules

Comment: `$rootRouter` acts as the connection between the Routers and the Location.
[AngularJS Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngComponentRouter/type/RootRouter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Router**

> Displays the Routing Components for the active Route. Manages
>   navigation from one component to the next

**RootRouter**

> The top level Router that interacts with the current URL location

Source found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router)